# Dynamic query pasting in Microsoft Excel

Tags: mysql, excel

i'm into a bit crazy situation, i've got an excel file with, let's say, 4 column.
Into the first, i've got a simple insert query:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(val_1,val_2,val_3) VALUES('val_1','val_2','val_3')
```

Into the other three columns are the values of the 'val_1','val_2' and 'val_3'. The file looks a bit like this:

```
        COLUMN 1                                          | val_1 | val_2 | val_3
INSERT INTO my_table(val_1,val_2,val_3) VALUES ('','','') |   aa  |  bb   |  cc
INSERT INTO my_table(val_1,val_2,val_3) VALUES ('','','') |   dd  |  ee   |  ff
```

hope you get the situation! Then my question is: is it possible to insert some special characters inside the query on clumn 1, that will allow me to copy and paste it in the rows below and making it catch the values in the same row?
i.e. for query one values are 'aa','bb' and 'cc', for query 2 values will be 'dd','ee','ff', and so on...

Sorry for my english and for my poor excel know-how!
Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is inconsistent.  Let me assume the first version.  You want to put in a formula like the following:

```
=substitute(substitute(substitute(A1, "'val_1'", "'"&B1&"'"), "'val_2'", "'"&c1&"'"), "'val_3'", "'"&"d1&"'")
```

This assumes the values are in the columns A-D and start in the first row.